# How to deserialize dictionary to an object in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

When I request to server, I receive a response as a dictionary:

```
    {
          data=({
            gender=female;
            id=3490074761922520002;
            name=joy;
            picture={
                  data={
                    url="";
                  };
            };
          },
          {
            gender=female;
            id=8242568878166175182;
            name="name";
            picture={
              data={
                url="";
              };
            };
          })
         paging={
            next="";
          }
         summary={
            "total_count"=66;
          };
     }
```

How can I deserialize this response dictionary to an object?

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: My response is a dictionary, not a JSON string

Comment: but this response above it seems a json document. All json are key/value pair. I think that response by trailmax is correct.

Comment: How are you serializing your json?

Comment: I use JsonConvert.SerializeObject from Newtonsoft.Json library

Comment: What does the dictionary you are serializing look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UPDATE ANSWER]
After 2 days searching for answer, I finally found the way to solve this issue.
Here is my code:

```
var err = new NSError();

var theJSONData = NSJsonSerialization.Serialize(response.Data, NSJsonWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, out err);

var theJSONText = new NSString(theJSONData, NSStringEncoding.UTF8);

Console.WriteLine(theJSONText);
```

response.data as NSDictionary -> JSON string

Answer (score 0):

Other way to desserealize is:

```
public async Task<List<Produto>> GetProdutosAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                string url = "http://www.something.com/api/produtos/";
                var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                var produtos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Produto>>(response);
                return produtos;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Change produto for your type.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but my response is NSDictionary type, not JSON